# Is the adverb 'just in time' still used adverbially when used in the sentence, "He is just in time?"

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs

Can this phrase ever be used adjectivally other than in a hyphenated way such as,'a just-in-time system'?

(I ask because in another language which I am learning, "He came just in time." is adjectival.)

Comment: In English "just in time" in your first example is not adjectival but an adjunct (adverbial). In "a just-in-time system", it's probably best classified as a compound adjective modifying "system".

Comment: Just-in-time systems are a separate thing about inventory and storage.